# No Output for the following "Fibonacci Series" code

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
n= int(input())
for i in range(n+1):
    def f(x):
        print(x)

        if i<=1:
            f(i)

        elif i>1:
            f(i-1) + f(i-2)
```

Comment: I think you have some things confused here. You are defining a function `n + 1` times inside the loop with `def f(x):` but never call it. This looks like you are trying to use a recursive and iterative approach together.

Comment: You have no base case and you have defined a function inside a loop. Does this even run?

Comment: isn't the function called after the if and elif statement?

Comment: @BhavikRoopchandani Not in the code you are showing. There is no f(n) being called anywhere. And even then your function is missing a return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your fibonacci function before, like this :

```
def f(x):
    if(x <= 1):
        return x
    else:
        return (f(x - 2)+ f(x - 1))
n = int(input())
print(f(n))
```

Comment: Could shorten this to `if x <= 1: return x`. Also would avoid the infinite recursion of something like `f(-1)`

Comment: Should be `<=`, `=<` is not valid syntax